# What is causing "fatal: repository 'https://github.com/bemyhre/my_web.git/' not found" error

Tags: git, github, terminal, repository

I am following the instructions to try and create a remote repository and it seems I cannot for some reason from my mac. Any input or help would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the set of terminal commands I have been using. Any thoughts?

```
Bens-MacBook-Pro:week7 benmyhre$ mkdir my_web
Bens-MacBook-Pro:week7 benmyhre$ cd my_web
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/benmyhre/Desktop/RubyProjects/week7/my_web/.git/
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ touch README
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git ad README
git: 'ad' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean one of these?
    add
    am
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git add README
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git commit -m 'first commit'
[master (root-commit) 4e7b51d] first commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git remote add origin https://github.com/bemyhre/my_web.git
Bens-MacBook-Pro:my_web benmyhre$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': #myusernamewenthere
Password for 'https://bemyhre@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/bemyhre/my_web.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the repository really exists. If you're trying to push to a repository that has not yet been created on GitHub, you'll get this error. More details https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found